# Coupon Collector Problem: probability of an r on the nth roll of k-sided die?

Tags: probability

How do I calculate the probability of rolling an *r* on the *n*th -- and only the *n*th -- throw of a *k*-sided fair die?

Comment: How many rolls are there in total?

Comment: Are you rolling the die until you get an $r$?  (I'm trying to square your question with the "coupon collector" in the title.)  If so, then the probability in question is $\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{k}\Bigr)^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Say I have a fair 6-sided die. I am trying to roll a 5. (When I do, I win the game.) I do NOT roll a 5 for 17 rolls. "Gee! That's highly unlikely. The probability of not throwing a 5 in 17 rolls is _____." Is the probability that on the 18th roll that I will throw a 5 (finally) still 1/6 or has it changed due to the prior 17 rolls? The Coupon Collector Problem makes it sound like my chance of missing for 18 rolls is quite low. But standard probability tells me that my probability is STILL 1/6. What am I missing?

Comment: Brian Tung, I didn't see your reply until after I sent my clarification. Thank you. I think you figured out what I (ham-fistedly) was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The probability of getting a specific number on a (fair) $k$-sided die is $1/k$. Thus, the probability of not getting it is $(k-1)/k$. Every roll is independent from the others.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- what is the prob of throwing it on the 1st roll? on the 2nd roll?

Can you generalize?

Geometric distribution will help quite a bit...